# Differentiability definition not working out

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have the piecewise defined function
$$
  f(x, y) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} & \text{if $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$} \\
                                   0 & \text{if $(x, y) = (0, 0)$}
  \end{cases}
$$

and I'm asked to find its derivative at the point $(0, 0)$ according to the vector $<2, 3>$.

My attempt was: since it may not be differentiable at the origin, I went through the definition for calculating the derivative:

$$f_x(x, y) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{|f(h, 0) - f(0, 0)|}{h} = 0 \\
f_y(x, y) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{|f(0, h) - f(0, 0)|}{h} = 0$$

So that, if differentiable, $\nabla f = <0, 0>$. I know it's not yet proved it is differentiable, but I went straight to thinking: if I check in the direction of the vector $<2, 3>$ I operate with the dot product and it of course gives me $0$. But the solutions of the manual give $\frac{18}{13}$.

Even if I partially derive the expression I always find the partial derivatives to be $(0, 0)$ at the origin. What am I thinking wrong by using the definition in this case? Shouldn't it always work with the definition?

Answer (score 2):

Directional derivative along a unit vector $\mathbf{u}=(a, b)$ is by definition $$D_\mathbf{u}f = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+ah, y+bh)-f(x, y)}{h}.$$ If $f$ is ***differentiable***, then it can be calculated by $\nabla f\cdot\mathbf{u}$. So you assumed the differentiability and got the wrong answer.

Comment: But I guess it is differentiable because the solutions give $\frac{18}{13}$ as an answer. So because it has a value, should it be differentiable?

Comment: @ludicrous No. Having a derivative in one or two or even a million directions is not enough to make a function (of two or more variables) differentiable. You should review the definition of differentiability of multi-variable functions.